# Hiding Multiple Rows at once where a cell in the row matches another cell

Tags: excel, vba

Use Case: For each cell in Column A (RangeK5:K700) that has the specific text ("Week 1" in this example) in cell B2, the row in the table that contains that specific text will be hidden.

I have code that works, but it takes a long time since the table I am currently 'filtering' is large and will get more rows as time goes on. I'm wondering if there is a way to speed up the code. I'm not much of an object oriented expert so I do tend to code the 'long' way. I think (my terminology will be incorrect so excuse me) that if I could somehow keep track of all of the rows to hide and then hide them at the end instead of at each loop, it would be faster. Is that possible?

I 'figured' this out by google searches & prayer so if there are any changes that can be made I'd appreciate hearing them. Thanks so much in advance!!

Note: B2 can have up to 13 different options (Week 1 --> Week 13 etc). I'll only show the code if B2 is "Week 1"

```
Sub CycleThroughWorksheet()
    Set Target = Range("B2")
    If Target.Value = "Week 1" Then
        Call HideWeek2
        Call HideWeek3
        Call HideWeek4
        Call HideWeek5
        Call HideWeek6
        Call HideWeek7
        Call HideWeek8
        Call HideWeek9
        Call HideWeek10
        Call HideWeek11
        Call HideWeek12
        Call HideWeek13
    End If
End Sub

------

Sub HideWeek1()
For Each Cell In Worksheets("Gantt Table").Range("K5:K700").Cells
If Cell.Text = "Week 1" Then
Cell.EntireRow.Hidden = True
End If
Next
End Sub

-------

Sub RunWeekView()
Call PreventScreenFlicker
Rows.EntireRow.Hidden = False
Call CycleThroughWorksheet
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can batch the hide operation like this:

```
Sub HideWeek(WeekNum As Long)
    Dim rng As Range
    For Each Cell In Worksheets("Gantt Table").Range("K5:K700").Cells
        If Cell.Text = "Week " & WeekNum Then
            If rng is nothing then
                Set rng = Cell
            Else
                Set rng = Application.Union(rng, Cell)
            End If  
        End If
    Next
    If not rng is nothing then rng.entirerow.hidden = true
End Sub
```

Call with (eg)

```
HideWeek 1
HideWeek 2
```

etc.

Depending on what the rest of your code looks like there are likely other changes you could make to reduce the size of your code.  If you're typically hiding most of the rows then it might be better to first hide everything, then only show the rows you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `Worksheet_Change` event to `AutoFilter` your data based on the value in `Range("B2")`. Right click your worksheet tab and select `View Code`, copy and place this code in your worksheet object code window in the Visual Basic for Applications window(the DEVELOPER tab must be enabled). When you change the `Week #` in the target cell(B2), the code will hide the rows that contain the target `Week #` in `Column K`, and show the other Weeks, by using `"<>"`, in the `Criteria1`.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B2")) Is Nothing Then
        With Range("K4", Range("K" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
            .AutoFilter 1, Criteria1:="<>" & Target.Value
        On Error Resume Next
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

If you actually want to only show the `Week #`, you can change to code by removing the `"<>"`...

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B2")) Is Nothing Then
        With Range("K4", Range("K" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
            .AutoFilter 1, Criteria1:= Target.Value
        On Error Resume Next
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```